# Add an "onclick" attribute to login submit button in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, drupal-7

I have a drupal proyect inside another page as an `iframe` and I want to add an attribute to the login submit button that redirect the top url to an custom url like this:

```
top.location.href = 'somepage.html';
```

I'm trying this:

```
  function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == 'user_login_block'){
      $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = array('onclick' => "top.location.href = 'somepage.html';");
    }
  }
```

I'm sure that the `$form_id` is `user_login_form`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Can you provide an jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the line from

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = array('onclick' => "top.location.href = 'somepage.html';");
```

to

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes'] = array('onclick' => "javascript: top.location.href = 'somepage.html';");
```